# Dojo subclass with different requires

Tags: javascript, dojo, subclass

If I have a class like the one below, is it possible to create a subclass with identical functionality but will override one of the "requires"?

I'm trying to use my own version of /registry in the example below. Thanks

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/query",
    "../registry",
], function(declare, query, registry){

    return declare("dijit.form._SearchMixin" {

    // Original Base code
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Though there was a neater solution to what I was trying to do but I guess I was over simplifying things. Answers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like that:

You have some class using modulA

```
define(["modulA"], function(modul){
  return declare("classA", [], {
    doSomething: function() {
      modul.doSomething()
    }
  })
});
```

and then you declare another class on the basis of classA, that should use modulB:

```
define(["classA", "modulB"], function(classA, modulB) {
  // do something magical so that doSomething will use modulB
  return declare("classB", [classA]) {}
})
```

it's not possible without overwriting all functions that use modulA. If it's your code, you can write it in the way that enables such polymorphism, using dynamic binding with module:

```
define([], function(){
  return declare("classA", [], {
    // dynamic binding, it can be overwritten
    modulName: "modulA",
    doSomething: function() {
        require([this.modulName, function(modul) {
                 // you must take into account, you're in async code now
          modul.doSomething()
        }  
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. The subclass is not really inheriting from the module that should be "dynamic", but it just depends on it.

If you would like to change a depending module, you could encapsulate it in a field inside your module, for example:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/query",
    "../registry"
], function(declare, query, registry) {

    return declare("dijit.form._SearchMixin", {
        registry: registry,

        aFunction: function() {
            this.registry.doStuff();
        }
    });
});
```

Now you could create a subclass of it and override the `registry` property. Just make sure that all interactions go through the module referenced by the `registry` property.

There are many cases where Dojo does this, it's used in the dropdowns, drag and drop, ... .